# DataTable with scroll Primefaces 3.0.M4

Tags: primefaces

I am using datatable component from PrimeFaces 3.0.M4 and I use the attribute `scrollable = true`. I would like to customize the scrollbar with my own style, but I can not find the CSS class.

Can anyone point me out the classes that customize the scrollbar? ( the arrows and the line).

Thank you

Comment: inspect the output ->
ui-datatable-scrollable && ui-datatabe-body-scrollable-body

Comment: I already did that but the properties seem to change only the panel background and not the actual scroll part.